# How to ignore SVN eligible merges

Tags: svn, merge

We use "**svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible**" command to make sure that every revision made on a given branch has been merged to the trunk.

But last week, we had some issues and had to manually merge a revision to the trunk (It doesn't really mater but a part of the revision was already merged and so on ...)

So now when we execute the previous command, the revision merge manually is listed whereas all needed files are already in the trunk.
My question is : **how to ignore a revision when checking merging with the previous command** ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the option `--record-only` with `svn merge` to mark a certain revision as merged without actually merging it. See the documentation of `svn merge` for details:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.record_only